# Django dynamic fields and cleaned_data

Tags: django, forms, dynamic

I have a complex dynamic form , where fields are being generated based on previous fields multiple times (for example I have a select field with football/basketball, when I choose football, all countries select is being generated, when choose country, leagues are generated and so on..)

I won't paste code here because it's too large. But the simple structure is

```
 def __init__(self, data=None, *args, **kwargs):
       super(tipForm, self).__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
       Based on some logic adding dynamic fields here.....
```

This is basic relation between fields: `Country->league->match->other(dateAndTime field, home/away team fields)`

My problem is that when the form is submitted and it passes all validations, in `cleaned_data` I have all keys of fields including dynamic fields, but for some reason country and league values are `empty/None/Null`. But for example match/(other) dynamic fields are present with values. So I am confused why last ones have values and others don't.

Match and other dynamic fields maybe present because they are basically last rendered dynamic fields. But still I don't get. Though `request.POST` has all data.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4294431/django-dynamically-added-form-fields-are-removed-in-form-cleaned-data) is another stackoverflow question. Where someone suggests that fields are not mapped correctly. But I don't think that's the point with my form.

Anyway if you will need maybe some more code part, I'll try to show/explain more.

---

**Update 1**

I found out that if just watch what is inside form.cleaned_data, then field league an country are none there , if write form.cleanded_data['league'] then it prints a League , but it prints not select option value , but text between tags Some text ....

Here is what request.POST , cleaned data returns .... some test .... :

**request.POST:**

```
<querydict: {u'initial-league':="" [u'45'],="" u'league':="" u'bettype':="" [u'hda'],="" u'bookie':="" [u'10bet'],="" u'handicap':="" [u'1.25'],="" u'country':="" [u'40'],="" u'odds':="" [u'1.11'],="" u'stake':="" [u'1'],="" u'prediction':="" [u'home'],="" u'initial-country':="" u'totalgoals':="" [u'+0.00'],="" u'initial-match':="" [u'12'],="" u'sport':="" u'initial-sport':="" u'match':="" [u'12']}=""></querydict:>
```

**form.cleaned_data:**

```
{'league': , 'bettype': u'hda', 'bookie': u'10bet', 'handicap': 1.25, 'country': , 'odds': 1.1100000000000001, 'stake': u'1', 'prediction': u'Home', 'sport': u'1', 'totalGoals': u'+0.00', 'match': u'12'}
```

**form.cleaned_data['league']:**

Blue Square Premier

**request.POST['league']:**

45

It feels like the data is there , but in different formats , and if u print it in general like form.cleaned_Data it shows that league is empty , although if u print form.cleaned_data['league'] , then it has value 'Blue square league' which comes from  Blue square League, but value 45 should be there ...

It's very confusing , maybe someone now has any idea what happens here with those dynamic fields ...

Comment: Have your written some custom validation of fields? If yes have you return the data after validating? You must return the data once it is validated. Post one custom field validation method if you have used it e.g. clean_my_field(self).

Comment: No i didn't write custom validation.... just create fields like this :
`self.fields[currentField] = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=model.objects.filter(**args),  initial=model.objects.filter(pk = data[currentField]), widget=forms.Select, show_hidden_initial=True)`

Comment: paste your complete form on pastebin or dpaste and share a link

Comment: it says unknown paste id, is it just me?

Comment: @Jingo http://pastebin.com/9MyFwzuQ   No , it's not just  you :).. i just put expiration date 1 hour... now it's one day.. Here's the code...

Comment: Hi there!, I dealt with something like this recently. Did you wrote custom validators for your fields?, if so, verify that you're returning the clean value properly on each validator. If not, try writing those custom validators. It would help if you post the entire code for your form. Also, check that you're not repeating field names.

Comment: I would start a debugger on your form is_valid method and see how it is accessing the fields, something should be missing there.

Comment: Could you re-post your complete code for form?